# How to git add 2 same files with same extensions but are in different folders

Tags: git

I have two files with the same names & extensions but in different folders. How to add both files to my git branch. I'm new to git so please help.

Files names are:

> `devices.js`

Answer (score 1):

If those 2 folders are placed in one folder you can do this

`git add path/to/folder/**/devices.js`

putting /**/ in the path will tell git to search in the path that to the left from /**/ and all it's subpaths.

You can read about that [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)(git documentation).

> A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.

If you are lazy and know that you don't have devices.js nowhere else in the project then you can just run `git add ./**/devices.js` from root directory of your project and it will match your files.